# How can I use an image on an HTML5 canvas without previously having an image on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, html5-canvas

On the [W3 Schools HTML5 Canvas Image Page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp), they use an `<img>` tag on the page before they load their canvas. Their code is below.

```
<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="scream" width="220" height="277" src="img_the_scream.jpg" alt="The Scream">

<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="240" height="297" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var img = document.getElementById("scream");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
}
</script>
```

I have a map (as an image) that I have loaded on a server that I need to use, but I cant find a way to only have the one image on the canvas. For example...
[image] The left one is the image that I am using, but I need it for the one on the right (which is a canvas) to work.

Any tips?

Comment: where does the image on the right come from,  can you get the "image" on the left as an SVG file, and how do you know where to put the colored wind (?) markers? Do you any code to show what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use JS to create an image

If you know the path to the image, or can provide it, you can use the following to create an image. It's important to note the image does take time to load and you **cannot** use the image successfully before it is loaded.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  var img = document.createElement("img");

  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
  }

  // triggers onload event (after it loads of course)
  img.src = "//via.placeholder.com/350x150";

}
```

```html
<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="370" height="170" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Comment: It seems that my other HTML canvas elements (arrows, text, and squares as shown in right side of image in question) does not show up. I have a promise function that is starting all of the code, but it still doesn't work. It seems as if it is going on top of the other elements.

Comment: Is there a simple way to wait till it is done? I tried to put my draw function into both a setTimeout and in the image onload function, but no luck.